# How to recover from a Silverlight UnhandledException

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, unhandled-exception

In my App() initialization code, I include a generic handler

```
UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
Debugger.Break();
}
```

I have 2 screens that work fine, but when navigating quickly back and forth between the two screens a number of times (varies between 7 and 12) I hit this breakpoint with the exception

```
{System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}   base {System.EventArgs}:   {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}  
    ExceptionObject: {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}  
    Handled: false
```

and if I remove the UnhandledException and set the Debugger to break on unhandled, I get the following:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application  
Code: 4004  
Category: ManagedRuntimeError  
Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 2028 An error has occurred. [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.ArgumentException: [Arg_ArgumentException]  
Arguments:  Debugging resource strings are unavailable.  
Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem.  
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_ArgumentException  
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)  
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection
```

even if I set `e.handled = true`, my application crashes.

**Important Note:**
The application, under a MVVM framework works over 99.9% of the time, navigating between dozens of screens.  Only one user has reported being able to crash the application by quickly navigating between two screens, and then only after about 10 back and forth tries

My questions are:

Any way to determine what is causing it?

Any way to prevent it?

What is the best way to recover from this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Followup:**

The problem was solved by naming the view control, even though that should not be needed

**from**

```
<telnav:RadTabItem.Content>
 <views:Detail_InfoView />
</telnav:RadTabItem.Content>
```

**to**

```
<telnav:RadTabItem.Content>
 <views:Detail_InfoView x:Name="DetailsInnerView"/>
</telnav:RadTabItem.Content>
```

Comment: That helped me too, very weird.

Comment: Wow... I've been banging my head on this same problem for a couple of days.  I was sure it was some weirdness related to refactoring some layout into a UserControl and/or getting the Bindings set right.  All that was needed was to set the 'x:Name' on the parent view (on the element that references the new UserControl) and the unhandled exception goes away.